# Dart: HTTP GET with Header

Tags: http, dart, flutter, lifx

I'm working on creating a Flutter application that works with LIFX. I'm trying to follow their instructions [here](https://lifx.readme.io/docs/list-lights), but I'm having issues adding a header to my HTTP GET request.

```
TestHttpGet() async {
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var header = "Bearer $token"; //token hidden
  var url = 'https://api.lifx.com/v1/lights/all/state';

  String result;
  try {
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set("Authorization", header);
    var response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
          var json = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
          print(json);
          var data = JSON.decode(json);
          result = data['brightness'].toString();
        } else {
          result =
              'Error getting response:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}';
        }
      } catch (exception) {
        result = 'Failed parsing response';
      }
```

This returns with `Error getting response: Http status 404`. I've tried various ways of `request.headers .set .add [HttpHeaders.Authorization] = "header"` all return with a 404. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the `authorization` header should be lower case, and either set or add will work.  Otherwise it seems like you might be having a problem with the API key.

Comment: Using cURL `Authorization` works, I tried using `authorization` in Flutter and that unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: This will work -> `http.get(url, headers:{"Authorization":"value"}).then(.....)`

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a `Map<String, String>` to the `http.get` call as the `headers` parameter like this:

```dart
await httpClient.get(url, headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
});
```

Comment: Also makes it lower case. I have the same issue. Putting in 'Authorization' results in lower caps 'authorization being written.

By the way you can use the url: http://postman-echo.com/headers to get all the headers as the server sees it as a json response

Answer (score 1):

In order to set headers you can't set the entire variable since it is set as final.  What you need to do is set the value of the individual array items which are also known as the individual "headers" in this case.

For example :

```
http.Request request = http.Request('GET', uri);
request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe dart makes all the fields of a HttpHeader to lowercase.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16665

The argument for that is because "Field names are case-insensitive". (otherwise it is not HTTP compliant)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2

Let me know if you found a workaround for this.